# How do I stop Excel Auto Update?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file (linked to software) of stock prices, the files gets updated prices from the software. However, I want the excel to update data only when I want (say F9). Please suggest.

I can get to this by (clicking on X for close), if I don't check the save/close/cancel option. The excel  doesn't update data and later when I want updated data I just press 'scape'. I was wondering if there is any other more robust method of getting it.

My excel is in manual calculation mode, external content (trust center) is disabled.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Please [edit] it to be clear. When you say "linked" are you referring to a data connection? Also, do not sign your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lot of information on this, including VB code to recalculate
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891(v=office.15).aspx